# How can I know which option is Renegade and which is Paragon?

Tags: mass-effect-3

So I noticed that when you're given two options at a decision point, the top option is usually the Paragon sounding option, and the bottom is usually the Renegade option.

Does this always hold out, so that when two options are presented, Paragon is always the top? It certainly seems to be the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, as a rule, Paragon options will always be at the top, and Renegade options will always be at the bottom. In some rare cases, the middle option will *also* be a Paragon or Renegade choice, possibly of less severity, but this is not common.

Keep in mind however, that while Paragon/Renegade options are always positioned at the appropriate corners, **dialog options at the corners are not always Paragon or Renegade**. While dialog at the corners will typically capture a Paragon or Renegade 'tone', this is not always the case, and there are plenty of conversations with no alignment consequences where the options do not correlate to an alignment per se.

Comment: Prime example of options not necessarily corresponding to alignment (which is a tiny bit confusing if you're assuming all do) is Yes/No questions.  Most times, Yes will be at the top and No will be at the bottom regardless of their association (or lack thereof) with an alignment.